# how to set toggle button text value from db on jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor, jtogglebutton

how to set toggle button text value (depend on database) on jtable

Here is the code

```
private class CheckBoxCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements

TableCellEditor, ItemListener {
    protected JToggleButton toggle;
    private String buttonValue;

    public CheckBoxCellEditor() {
        toggle = new JToggleButton("off");
        toggle.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);           
        toggle.addItemListener(this);
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        buttonValue = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
        return toggle;
    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue() {    
        // System.out.println( buttonValue);    
        return buttonValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            toggle.setText("On!");
            System.out.println(buttonValue);
        } else {
            toggle.setText("Off");
            System.out.println(buttonValue);
        }    
    }
}
```

Here the image shows the toggle but it's not shows the text.

when i click the button the text shows then click next button the 1st one is not visible.

[image]

if you know the answer please share here..
with regards...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've forgotten to set the value of the toggle button before returning it from the `getTableCellEditorComponent`

```
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table,
        Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {


    buttonValue = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
    toggle.setText(buttonValue);


    return toggle;
}
```

To be honest, I'm curious with what's wrong with returning `Boolean` from `getColumnClass` in the table model for the `Return` column and simply let the default renderer and editor deal with it...

Also...you're ignore the button value when you return it from the editor...

```
public Object getCellEditorValue() {

    // System.out.println( buttonValue);

    return buttonValue;
}
```

Frankly, probably better to use `toggle.getText()`...

Comment: @mKorbel Just realised that the supplied code doesn't actually implement  TableCellRenderer